# Access const correctly a row of an Eigen Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, c++14, constants, eigen

It seems from the [signiture of the row() function](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a09bc4a61cdf4ad219db0e70de12c2ae2) in Eigen that it isn't `const` so you are not able to call this function on a const reference e.g. `const Matrix& x` `x.row(i);` is not allowed.

*What is the best practice if I need a const method for getting the
   the i-th row of x?*

*Do you know the reason why isn't the `row()` function const?*

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Matrix;

void func(const Matrix& x) {
    // Something something
    x.row(i); // Error: Non-const function row called on const object 
    // Something something
}
```

Disclaimer: My question is pretty obvious, probably it takes 2 seconds for an experienced `Eigen` dev, apologies the banality. Feel free to close the post if you are convinced the answer is obvious. I tried the C++ chat without someone knowing the answer.

Comment: you could do it like `const_cast<Matrix&>(x).row(i);`

Comment: In my experience, Eigen doesn’t care much for const correctness. Just take non-const references to your matrices, even if you don’t intend to modify them. Or cast constness away, but that doesn’t make stuff any prettier.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the comment! I'm sad to hear your comment about the quality of Eigen. Could it be that const-ness is added by some tempalte parameter deduction or something, I saw the Ref class in Eigen, that could maybe usable here.

Comment: @mdatsev Good, valid answer to my question, thanks and it works, ordo  I'm not sure if it would be safe to take away const-ness :-s.

Comment: Well if the original object wasn't const and just the reference is const then it isn't a problem.

Comment: Actually there seems to be a const version of row() https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a624618f6fe2271dbd70699c00c2501f5

Comment: yes of course there is a const version of `row(Index)`, and don't worry Eigen is const-correct. If someone found constness hole, please report a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using <strike>an outdated</strike> a broken version of Eigen.  The following code compiles just fine with Eigen 3.3.

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Matrix;

void func(const Matrix& x) {
    x.row(0);
}

int main() {
    Matrix m = Matrix::Random(2,2);
    func(m);
}
```

---

By the way, **under no circumstances** do

```
void func(const Matrix& x) {
    const_cast<Matrix&>(x).whatever();
}
```

This invokes undefined behaviour!  The only reason `const_cast` exists is to be compatible with legacy C interfaces where const correctness might not be present.  Never cast away constness to call a const member function of a const object.

Comment: and it has always compiled as the const version of `row` has always existed.

Comment: @ggael Edited accordingly.